# MC.User.login -> MC is unknown

Tags: monaca

Probably a simple answer but where comes the MCobject from? How can I set it. I Keep getting an error that states that MC is unknown in the following code:

```
MC.User.login(email, password)
.done(function()
{
  console.log('Login is success!');
  getMemoList();
  $.mobile.change('#ListPage');
})
.fail(function(err)
{
  console.log(err.message);
  alert('Login failed!');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong API structure.  For javascript, use these docs:  https://docs.monaca.io/en/reference/monaca_api/cloud/

Specifically, for login:

```
    monaca.cloud.User.login("me@example.com", "password")
.done(function(result){
   console.log("Hello again, " + result.user._username);
})
.fail(function(err)
{
   console.log("Err#" + err.code +": " + err.message);
});
```

You are getting an error, because it is not `MC` but `monaca.cloud`.....

Comment: Exactly! On Monaca Backend Memo template, `MC` is used but it's also defined as `var MC = monaca.cloud;`